# MVVM architecture: one model - several view models + place for data access

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, architecture

I'm quite confused about the architecture of my MVVM application (formerly WinRT, now targeting UWP) concerning data access. I'm quite unsure how to propagate changes across the UI and where to put access to the data layer.

Here's the basic architecture:

1. **Model layer:** contains models that only have auto properties (no navigation properties that reference other models, just Ids; so they are basically just representations of the database). They don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
2. **Data acccess layer:** A repository that uses sqlite-net to store models in a database. It exposes the basic CRUD operations. It returns and accepts model from the model layer.
3. **ViewModels**:

   - **ViewModels for the Models**: They wrap around the models and expose properties. Sometimes I two-way bind content of controls (e.g. TextBoxes) to properties. The setters then access the data layer to persist this change.
   - **PageViewModels for Views**: They contain ViewModels from above and Commands. Many Commands have become very long as they do the data access, perform domain specific logic and update the PageViewModels properties.
4. **Views (Pages)**: They bind to the PageViewModels and through DataTemplate to the ViewModels for the models. Sometimes there is two-way databinding, sometimes I use Commands.

I now have several problems with this architecture:

*Problem 1:* One model can be represented on the screen at several palaces. For example, a master-detail view that displays a list of all available entities of a type. The user can select one of them and its content is displayed in the detail view. If the user now changes a property (e.g. the model's name) in the detail view, the change should be immediatelly reflected in the master list. What is the best way of doing this?

1. Have **one ViewModel for the model**? I don't think this makes much sense, as the master list needs only very little logic, and the detail view much more.
2. Let the **model implement INotifyPropertyChanged** and thus propagate the change to the ViewModels? The problem I have with this, is that the data layer currently doesn't guarantee that the objects it returns for two read operations on one model id are identical - they just contain the data read from the database and are newly created when they are read (I think that's the way sqlite-net works). I'm also not really sure how to avoid memory leaks happening because of all the PropertyChanged event subscriptions from the ViewModels. Should I implement IDisposable and let the PageViewModel call its children's Dispose() method?
3. I currently have a **DataChanged event on my data access layer**. It is called whenever a create, update or delete operation occurs. Each ViewModel that can be displayed simultaneously listens to this event, checks whether the changed model is the one its the ViewModel for and then updates its own properties. Again I have the problem of the memory leak and this becomes slow, as too many ViewModels have to check whether the change is really for them.
4. Another way?

*Problem 2:* I'm also not sure whether the place I access data is really well chosen. The PageViewModels have become extremely convoluted and basically do everything. And all ViewModels require knowledge of the data layer with my architecture.

**I've been thinking of scrapping data access with sqlite-net and using Entity Framework 7 instead.** Would this solve the problems above, i.e. does it guarantee object identity for one model when I use the same context? I also think it would simplify the ViewModels as I rarely need read operations, as this is done through navigation properties.

I've also been wondering whether having two way databinding is good idea at all in a MVVM application, as it requires the property setter to call the data access layer to persist the changes. Is it better to do only one-way binding and persist all changes through commands?

I'd be really happy if someone could comment on my architecture and suggest improvements or point to good articles on MVVM architecture that focus on my problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Have one ViewModel for the model? I don't think this makes much sense, as the master list needs only very little logic, and the detail view much more.

ViewModel is not dependent on the model. ViewModel uses the model to address the needs of the view. ViewModel is the single point of contact for the view so whatever the view needs the viewmodel has to provide. So it can be a single model/multiple models. But you can break down a single ViewModels into multiple sub ViewModels to make the logic easier. Its like detail pane can be separated into a user control with its own view model. Your master page will just have the window that will host this control and the MasterViewmodel will push the responsibilities to the sub ViewModel.

> 2. Let the model implement INotifyPropertyChanged and thus propagate the change to the ViewModels? The problem I have with this, is that
>      the data layer currently doesn't guarantee that the objects it returns
>      for two read operations on one model id are identical - they just
>      contain the data read from the database and are newly created when
>      they are read (I think that's the way sqlite-net works). I'm also not
>      really sure how to avoid memory leaks happening because of all the
>      PropertyChanged event subscriptions from the ViewModels. Should I
>      implement IDisposable and let the PageViewModel call its children's
>      Dispose() method?

The danger is not using `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but as your rightly said its with the subcribing and unsubscribing. Wherever there is a need to subscribe to any event - not only `INotifyPropertyChanged` you need to use `IDisposable` to unsubscribe itself and its child ViewModels. I am not clear on the datalayer you describe, but if it publishes the property changed event for any modification I dont see any problem using `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

> 3.I currently have a DataChanged event on my data access layer. It is called whenever a create, update or delete operation occurs. Each
>   ViewModel that can be displayed simultaneously listens to this event,
>   checks whether the changed model is the one its the ViewModel for and
>   then updates its own properties. Again I have the problem of the
>   memory leak and this becomes slow, as too many ViewModels have to
>   check whether the change is really for them.

As I said earlier, if you handle the subscribe/unsubscribe properly for all models you need not worry about performance issue of INotifyPropertyChanged. But what might be adding to the problem is the number of calls you make to the database for requesting data. Have you considered using Async...Await for the data access layer which will not block the UI for any update thats happening. Even if the data update is slow a reactive UI which doesnt get blocked by the data calls is a better option.

So try adding a data access service which is abstracted over the DAL layer and provide a asynchronous approach to accessing the data. Also have a look at the [Mediator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). That might prove helpful.

> I'm also not sure whether the place I access data is really well
>   chosen. The PageViewModels have become extremely convoluted and
>   basically do everything. And all ViewModels require knowledge of the
>   data layer with my architecture.

2 main problems i see,

1. If you feel the PageViewModel is too huge break down into sub view models of manageable size. Its very subjective, so you have to try to see what all parts can be broken down to its own component/usercontrol with its own viewmodel.
2. When you say *ViewModels require knowledge of data layer*, I hope you mean they are dependent on a Interface that manages the DAL layer services and doesn't have direct access to class with CRUD methods. If not try to add an abstract layer which does you actually do in your view model. And that will handle the DAL CRUD operations.

> I've been thinking of scrapping data access with sqlite-net and using
>   Entity Framework 7 instead.

Don't try to replace sqlite-net with EF without hard evidence. You need to measure performance in your app before trying to jump into such big changes. What if the problem lies in your code rather than the component you are using. First try to fix the above mentioned issues then you can segregate the DAL layer via interfaces and replace it if needed.

> I've also been wondering whether having two way databinding is good
>   idea at all in a MVVM application, as it requires the property setter
>   to call the data access layer to persist the changes. Is it better to
>   do only one-way binding and persist all changes through commands?

If you are making a call to database directly everytime you make a change to the field/ for every key stroke then its a problem. Then you should have a Copy of the Data Model and persist the changes only when you click the save button.

Comment: I think I'm going to add a data service layer, currently all ViewModels access interfaces of the DAL. My data access already is async, but I'm considering of making it **synchronous** , as I typically have many hundreds of read operations in a row. (Fewer but more complex would require direct exposure of sqlite-net functionality.) This slows down performance, as there is the overhead of creating Tasks for each little request (that's the way sqlite-net does it), and it also prevents the use of transaction. So access to the DAL would be sync, but the new data service layer would be async.

Comment: And thanks for your long answer, CarbineCoder! This already helped me quite a bit.

Comment: Cheers... I am glad it was helpful. You dont have to worry about overhead of task creation unless you are doing it wrong. Idea of data service layer is good and needed. Unless you have proof that async is causing the problem dont remove it. You might end up harming the system by doing pre-mature optimization without proof. I recommend dont do it unless you can mock up your  approach and measure the difference.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. You should never persist changes directly to the database, especially not in the property. Properties should be fast, doing long running operations blocks them and the workarounds for this are awful and bad. Persist via commands, they are awaitable